# How to login and proceed with Scraping in JAVA?

Tags: java, web, web-scraping

My problem is that I must be able to **extract** certain **information** such as the price, quantity and name of each product on a website selling electronic products and devices ([this website](https://www.elit.com.ar/)), but the drawback is that in order to see this information you must first **login**, therefore I must login and then extract all the information. But my current code does not allow me to do this, it extracts information from me, but it is the same information I get without logging in.

**My code**

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.elit.com.ar/productos/computadoras.html")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.elit.com.ar/productos/computadoras.html")
                    .data("username", username)
                    .data("password", password)
                    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
                    .timeout(100000)
                    .post();
            System.out.println(document.getAllElements());
```

Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to **Scraping** and mainly **Java**. Thank you and I look forward to your support.

Comment: You should use the cookies after signing in not before

Comment: I already tried without the use of Cokiees and I still don't get the elements where the price, quantity, etc. should be. just the basics that show without logging in. Thank you

Comment: you need to use the cookies after signing in. Right now you are using the cookies on sign in

Comment: Could you show me a small fraction of code to better understand? sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 2):

You need to first post the data to the login url and use the cookies from there.

Since I don't have a valid credentials to test I don't know what the auth flow on the site is.

But here is a gist

```
   // get login form
    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("https://www.elit.com.ar/clientes/login.html")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .execute();

    // POST login data
    Connection.Response loginResponse = Jsoup.connect("https://www.elit.com.ar/clientes/login.html")
        .data("username", username)
        .data("password", password)
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .timeout(100000)
        .post();

    // GET page
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.elit.com.ar/productos/computadoras.html")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET)
        .cookies(loginResponse.cookies())
        .timeout(100000)
        .execute();
    System.out.println(document.getAllElements());
```

I suggest you take a look at this article and understand how the auth flow works on the site you are **scraping**

http://joelmin.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html

Comment: Friend, the login proceeds successfully. I only had to make some changes in the second fraction of code had to be an excute() and in the third a get() but I am wrong. But at the moment of obtaining the products they are not obtained with all the information :-(.